# Why this counter is given me the wrong avarage?

Tags: python, list, count

Given a list of numbers in the first list for the multiple of three in the first list determines a range in the second list I have to find the average of all of the numbers in that range and also the min and max numbers I got the min a max right but I got the average wrong what did I miss?

```
v1 = [2,3,4,6,2]
v2 = [4,6,7,4,9,3,4,5,5,45,5,4]
vm3 = []

for i in v1:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        vm3.append(i)
        
mayl = []
menl = []
proml = []

for i in vm3:
    may = v2[i-1]
    men = v2[i-1]
    prom = 0
    for j in range(i):
        prom = prom + v2[j]
        if v2[j] > may:
            may = v2[j]
        elif v2[j] < men:
            men = v2[j]
        
    mayl.append(may)
    menl.append(men)
    proml.append(prom/i+1)
    
        
print(mayl)
print(menl)
print(proml)
```

I am getting the output:

```
[7, 9]
[4, 3]
[6.666666666666667, 6.5]
```

but this is wrong since 4+6+7+4 = 21/4 = 5.25 not 6.6 where is the error?

Comment: Could you please rewrite your description more clearly? That opening passage is very hard to follow, it looks like it should be several sentences. Also, the code doesn't help me understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: for example, 3 is a multiple of three and is in the first list so that determines a range in the second list from 0 to 3 then I have to find the average of all the numbers in that second list in that range in this case 4+6+7+4 = 21/4 = 5.25

Comment: `prom/i+1` Order of operations.  This divides `prom/i`, then adds 1.  Did you intend that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You're not summing `4+6+7+4`, `i` is `3`, so you're only getting the first *three* elements, `4`, `6` and `7`.
2. `proml.append(prom/i+1)` isn't properly computing the average either way. If you intended to count four items when `i == 3`, then your precedence was wrong. `/` binds more tightly than `+`, so you were computing, `(prom/i)+1` when you needed `proml.append(prom/(i+1))` (and in that case, your inner loop should be `for j in range(i+1):`, not `range(i)`, to actually read all values up to and including index `3`). If you intended to count just three items, then `proml.append(prom/i)` is correct, adding `1` would be treating it as if you had summed four values.